# How to add minutes to HH:MM:SS in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, date, time, datetime-conversion

I want to add Minutes (typeof Integer) to HH:MM:SS (typeof String).

Example:

```
let min = 125;
let time = "10:00:00";
```

**Result = "12:05:00"**

Comment: Please post your code of attempts to accomplish this.

Comment: For anything datetime related in JavaScript I always use momentjs while it is easy to use and understand, it always get the job done easy

Comment: Do you want to get a time information as result or do you want to get a duration in hours. minutes and seconds?

Comment: @Marc in HH:MM:SS

Comment: Every answer solves my query. Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy is to convert the values to a common component like seconds, add the values, then format as H:mm:ss. General functions usually have wider applicability than *ad hoc* ones, so given that you have minutes as a number it would be better to refactor it to a string in the call, e.g.

```js
/** Add times, only deals with positive values
** @param {string} t0 : time in h[:mm[:ss]] format
** @param {string} t1 : time in same format as t0
** @returns {string} summ of t0 and t1 in h:mm:ss format
**/
function addTimes(t0, t1) {
  return secsToTime(timeToSecs(t0) + timeToSecs(t1));
}

// Convert time in H[:mm[:ss]] format to seconds
function timeToSecs(time) {
  let [h, m, s] = time.split(':');
  return h*3600 + (m|0)*60 + (s|0)*1;
}

// Convert seconds to time in H:mm:ss format
function secsToTime(seconds) {
  let z = n => (n<10? '0' : '') + n; 
  return (seconds / 3600 | 0) + ':' +
       z((seconds % 3600) / 60 | 0) + ':' +
        z(seconds % 60);
}

let min = 125;
let time = "10:00:00";

console.log(addTimes('0:'+ min, time));

// or

console.log(addTimes(secsToTime(min * 60), time));
```

The above *addTimes* function doesn't handle negative values. If you wan to do that, there's a little more work to handle the sign, particularly for output:

```js
/** Add times
** @param {string} t0 : time in [-]h[:mm[:ss]] format
** @param {string} t1 : time in same format as t0
** @returns {string} summ of t0 and t1 in h:mm:ss format
**/
function addTimes(t0, t1) {
  return secsToTime(timeToSecs(t0) + timeToSecs(t1));
}

// Convert time in H[:mm[:ss]] format to seconds
function timeToSecs(time) {
  let sign = /^-/.test(time);
  let [h, m, s] = time.match(/\d+/g);
  return (sign? -1 : 1) * (h*3600 + (m|0)*60 + (s|0)*1);
}

// Convert seconds to time in H:mm:ss format
function secsToTime(seconds) {
  let sign = seconds < 0? '-':'';
  seconds = Math.abs(seconds);
  let z = n => (n<10?'0':'') + n;
  return sign +
         (seconds / 3600 | 0) + ':' +
       z((seconds%3600) / 60 | 0) + ':' +
        z(seconds%60);
}

let min  = -125;
let time = "10:00:00";

// Convert min to a timestamp in the call
console.log(addTimes(secsToTime(min * 60), time));
```

Note that there is no integer type in ECMAScript, there is only [number](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-type).

Comment: What will you get if you add 262080 minutes to "10:00:00" (182 days)?

Comment: @Marc—you'll get `(262080 / 60) + 10` hours, or 4378:00:00.

Comment: You code is correct if you want to get a duration. something like this. 4378h . In my understanding Shubham wants to get a time as result.  Shubham  should make a comment want his intention is.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
let min = 125;

let time = "10:00:00";

console.log(addtime(time,min));

function addtime(time,hour){
  let times=time.split(":");
  //clear here more than 24 hours
  min=min%(24*60);
  times[0]=(parseInt(times[0]))+parseInt(min/60) ;
  times[1]=parseInt(times[1])+min%60;
  //here control if hour and minutes reach max
  if(times[1]>=60) { times[1]=0 ;times[0]++} ;
  times[0]>=24 ?  times[0]-=24  :null;
  
  //here control if less than 10 then put 0 frond them
  times[0]<10 ? times[0]= "0" + times[0] : null ;
  times[1]<10 ? times[1]= "0" + times[1] : null ;
  
  return times.join(":");
}
```

Comment: For this input "23:00:00" you would get  "25:05:00"

Comment: Sorry. Try this : let min = 60 * 48 + 10;

Comment: And the jump of winter to summer time?  A non date solution is not robust, I'm afraid.

Comment: But he doesn't have day time. only have hour. So there can't be summer time here.  If he had time , there can be also day information. He only tries to increase hour. If he just try add hour to string then summer time also gives him wrong result also timezone gives him wrong result.

Comment: No, you are completely wrong. Run your code 10 minutes before a winter / summer time jump. You will see...

Comment: I don't agree . There is no time here there is no date here . There is only hour here and user only increase hour . For example why are u using german timezone in your answer. Maybe user is not in Germany. You are wrong because you have timezone problem in your answer

Comment: Trust me. It is a typical problem. I saw it often at Deutsche Bahn (German railway).

Comment: @Marc—the OP is about adding minutes to a time. There is no concept of date. The issue with daylight saving is a local issue on specific dates and can be addressed by adding time to UTC, then converting to local.

Comment: What will you get if you add 262080 minutes to "10:00:00" (182 days)?

Comment: As I only want to get end time of a particular movie show from its movie length. So this answer also solves my query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick function to just **add minutes** to a time string **HH:MM:SS**.
Does not affect the seconds and just manipulates the minutes and hours.
Can be improved, but is only a quick solution.
With few test examples below.

```js
 function timeAddMinutes(time, min) {
var t = time.split(":"),      // convert to array [hh, mm, ss]
    h = Number(t[0]),         // get hours
    m = Number(t[1]);         // get minutes
m+= min % 60;                 // increment minutes
h+= Math.floor(min/60);       // increment hours
if (m >= 60) { h++; m-=60 }   // if resulting minues > 60 then increment hours and balance as minutes

return (h+"").padStart(2,"0")  +":"  //create string padded with zeros for HH and MM
       +(m+"").padStart(2,"0") +":"
       +t[2];                        // original seconds unchanged
}  

// ======= example tests =============
console.log(timeAddMinutes('10:00:00', 125));        // '12:05:00'
console.log(timeAddMinutes('10:47:00', 4*60+15));    // '15:02:00'
console.log(timeAddMinutes('10:00:00', 0));          // '10:00:00'
console.log(timeAddMinutes('10:00:00', 60+17));      // '11:17:00'
console.log(timeAddMinutes('00:30:00', 30));         // '01:00:00'
console.log(timeAddMinutes('05:45:00', 45));         // '06:30:00'
console.log(timeAddMinutes('10:00:00', 60*100+5));   // '110:05:00'
```

Comment: This is not a time I think : '110:05:00'. Its more a duration like 110h 5m .

Comment: @Marc. True. I just added it as an example for anything more than 23 hours. He could convert that into days if he likes.

Comment: As I only want to get end time of a particular movie show from its movie length. So this answer also solves my query. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

First you have to parse the text, then create a date object, then add 125 minutes (in millis) and last but not least you can format the created date:

```js
let min = 125;
let [hh, mm, ss] = "10:00:00".split(':').map(s=>parseInt(s, 10));

const d = new Date();
d.setHours(hh);
d.setMinutes(mm);
d.setSeconds(ss);
const result = new Date(d.getTime() + 125 * 60 * 1000);
console.info(result); // result is the date with the correct time
    
// formatting the output:
const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
});

const [,,,,,,{value:hour},,{value: minute},,{value: second}] = dateTimeFormat.formatToParts(result);
console.info(`${hour}:${minute}:${second}`);
```

--> 12:05:00

I think that all other answers in this post (without date object) are incorrect.

You can make a doublecheck with moment.js:

```
let now = new Date();
var date = moment(new Date(), "hh:mm:ss");
console.info(date.format('LTS')); // -> 7:50:37 AM

date = date.add(262080 , 'minutes');
console.info(date.format('LTS')); // -> 6:50:37 AM
```

See: [codepen](https://codepen.io/krocon/pen/MWaxBza)

Comment: As I only want to get end time of a particular movie show from its movie length. So this answer also solves my query. Thanks